# Join two graphs (one beside other) GWAS

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, datagrid

I have this code to generate 2 different types of graphs (manhattan plot and a QQ plot)

```
# Set up the work directory in which all data is gonna be extracted
gwasResults2 = read.csv("DWStem.csv") #Change name of the file
library(qqman) #Run to create plots
library(cowplot)
library(extrafont)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(gridExtra)
MH <- manhattan(gwasResults2, chr="CHR", bp="BP", snp="SNP", p="P", 
                     col = c("chartreuse2", "darkorange1", "gold1"),ylim=c(0,-log10(1e-06)), chrlabs = NULL,
                     suggestiveline = -log10(1e-03), genomewideline = -log10(1e-05),
                     highlight = NULL, logp = TRUE, annotatePval = NULL,
                     annotateTop = TRUE, main='DWStem')
QQ <- qq(gwasResults2$P, main='DWStem', pch = 24, cex=1, col="gold", bg="brown1", lwd=1, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5)) #Run to create qqplot $P need to be there!

Total <- plot_grid(MH, QQ, labels = c("a", "b"), ncol = 2)
```

But apparently I cant put them aside each other because I get the next error:

> Error in plot_to_gtable(x) : 
>         Argument needs to be of class "ggplot", "gtable", "grob", "recordedplot", or a function that plots to an R graphicsdevice when called, but is a list

Any idea of how I can solve it? 
In advance, thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

The functions `manhattan` and `qq` produce base graphics, not grid graphics.  You need to use base graphics methods for the layout.  For example, using reproducible data,

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
manhattan(gwasResults, main = "a")
qq(gwasResults$P, main = "b")
```

produces

[image: screenshot]

If your plots used grid graphics (produced by `grid`, `ggplot2` or `lattice`), your method would have worked.  If some use grid and some use base graphics, it is possible to mix them in the same display, but it is not easy. See the `gridBase` and `gridGraphics` packages.

EDITED to add:

If you have `gridGraphics` installed, then it's actually not so bad to mix the base graphics with grid graphics.  You just set `MH` and `QQ` to be functions producing the graphs, rather than the graphs themselves.  For example,

```
MH <- function() { manhattan(gwasResults) }
QQ <- function() { qq(gwasResults$P) }
Total <- plot_grid(MH, QQ, labels = c("a", "b"), ncol = 2)
```

When you print `Total`, you get this:

[image: screenshot]

The graphs have lost their y axis labels, but otherwise look okay.